# Weighted activity selection with partly overlaping times

Tags: algorithm

Let us assume that we have n schedules . Each schedule i has a weight w(i) , a preperation time prep(i) and a rest time rest(i) .

Preperation time means that if we choose schedule i , we are obliged not to choose schedules i - prep(i) , i - prep(i) + 1 ... i-1  .

Rest time means that if we choose shedule i ,we are obliged not to choose shedules i+1 ,i+2 ... i+rest(i)

Our task is to choose appropriate schedules according to the above restrictions ,in order to maximize W.

Note: For i=1 ,we ignore prep(i) .We assume that we are already prepared.For i=n wh ignore rest(i).

Restriction : Preparation time of one schedule can overlap with rest time of another schedule .   To give an example , if we have rest(5)=2   , prep(8)=2  ,we are able to choose both schedules .  rest(5)=2 means that if we choose 5 ,we are not allowed to choose 6 and 7 . Prep(8)=2 means that if we choose 8 ,we are not allowed to choose 6 and 7 .  So we can choose both 5 and 8.

What is the most suitable algorithm for this task?

If it wasn't for the restriction , we could say that each schedule has start time i - prep(i) and finish time i + rest (i) . We would have a weighted activity selection problem , so we would had been able to get an optimal O(nlogn) with a greedy algorithm . But the restriction spoils my plan.

Answer (score 1):

Let `f(i)` be the optimal answer such that `i`-th activity is the last one. We can go from activity `j` to activity `i` if `j < prep(i)` and `j + rest(j) < i`. Put it another way, `f(i) = (max of f(j) among all valid j such that j < prep(i) and j + rest(j) < i) + 1`. This formula leads to a straightforward `O(N^2)` solution.

But we can do better! Let's keep a persistent segment tree for maximum operation (one version for each position in the array). Initially, it is filled with zeros. For a fixed `i`, we go the `prep(i) - 1` version and perform a maximum query on the `[0, i - 1]` range. Then `f(i)` is the value of this maximum plus one. After that, we update the tree (that is, create a new version) in the position `i + rest(i)` with `f(i)`. That's it.

We do `O(N)` get maximum and update one element queries to a persistent segment tree, so the solution requires `O(N log N)` time and space, which looks pretty good. However, it seems to be quite complicated.

Now let's get rid of persistence. We can keep a "normal" (that is, non-persistent segment tree) and update the value in a position `i` with `f(i)` when after we reach `j = i + rest(i)` (by keeping, let's say, a vector of elements to be added at each position). We don't need to care about the second restriction anymore. Thus, `f(i)` is the maximum in the range `[0, prep(i) - 1]` plus one. After finding `f(i)`, we push into the to be added vector for the `i + rest(i)` position.

It still uses `O(N log N)` time, but the space complexity is now linear and we don't need a persistent segment tree anymore (in fact, each update can only increase the value and we need a maximum value on a prefix, so we can use a binary index tree instead of a segment tree here).